# Track Page Hits on Hundreds of Imported Pages on Local Server

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

We have created a landing page that links to various materials (i.e. Khan Academy, Wikipedia, TED, etc.) which are hosted in sub-directories on the raspberry pi server (this is to say that they are not linked to the original source but reside directly on the server).

What I would like to do is write a PHP or shell script to track when users have accessed any of the pages of these materials. Ideally, this would track the time visited, the IP address, and other pertinent information. I know I could go through every page and add a PHP script to the top of each page, but we are talking about 100s if not 1000s of pages which is just not feasible.

As to my question, is it possible to either (1) track visits on these links using one shell or PHP script or (2) loop through all web (i.e. PHP, HTML) files and add a script to the top of each page? If so, how would I do this?

Thanks for any help you could give.

This is for a raspberry pi that runs a local ubuntu server with MySQL, PHP, and Apache.

Comment: Both are possible :)

Comment: You could process the Apache log file using any number of languages :)

Comment: Thanks! Great. I will look into processing the Apache log file. Any other ideas or further direction will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: @misorude This is great! This works for PHP files. Is there a way to get this to work for HTML files as well?

Comment: You’d have to configure the server to parse .htm(l) files as PHP as well - do a bit of research, there should be plenty explanations on how to get that to work on different systems.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! For those who have the same problem, these two links look promising: https://websistent.com/php-auto_prepend_file-and-auto_append_file/ and https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/